# Outputing to .txt file

Tags: c#, .net

I am a little stuck.  I have to use the `getItems` method and output it to PrintItems.txt, but I am not sure how to appoach this problem.

This is my `GetItems` method:

```
public string getItems()
{
    string strout = "stock items " + "\n";
    foreach (Stock  s in  stock)
    {
        strout = strout + s.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    return strout;
}
```

This is my `PrintItems` method:

```
string filename = "printitems.txt";
int count = 0;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    while (count < 5 && count < stock.Count)
    {
        Stock t = stock[count];
        sw.WriteLine(t);
        count++;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because it doesn't write to a file at all.

Comment: Does it error?  Are you _sure_ it doesn't write to a file - IE perhaps "printitems.txt" is not appearing in the folder you're expecting, since you've not specified a path for it etc.  Also `getItems` isn't being used by your file writing code?

Comment: Have you checked in the `/bin` directory for the file?

Comment: You need to output the return value of getItems()? Then why do you not even call the function?

Comment: @Kyborek I am not sure how to call It

Answer (score 2):

You code generally should work.

But since you haven't specified full path to the text file - it will be created in the same folder where your executable file is.

If you running it from Visual Studio - it should be in `your_project\bin\Debug` or `your_project\bin\Release` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\dummy.txt", strout);
```

(As long as you don't expect the string to be massive - i.e. 10MB)

'File' uses System.IO

Answer (score 0):

If you made no copy & paste error then there are 4 possibilities for your pheonomenon:

```
        string filename = "printitems.txt";
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {

            while (count < 5 && count < stock.Count)
            {
                Stock t = stock[count];
                sw.WriteLine(t.ToString());
                count++;
            }
        }
```

You had no { after the streamwriter using line was something I saw first. The second thing is that Stock t normally can't be written directly but instead you need to do the same thing as when printing it out to the console.

Third: your code does not say anything about if stock is filled or not.

Fourth: The file: You should specify a directory (not only the filename) as else it can be that it is tried to create the file in a location where you have no permissions to create a file in (normally if you put no additional path info in the same path as where the application runs in is used [if you start from the visual studio itself then the appropraite bin path] as location where the file would be created).

Additionally: You should put a try catch block around the whole thing as there can be unexpected phenomenons which result in an exception.